# How to set a Mixer's volume to a slider's volume in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio, uislider, mixer

I'm trying to make some audio settings. Here is my script:

```
public AudioMixer masterMixer;
public float masterLvl;
public float musicLvl;
public float sfxLvl;

public void SetMasterVolume ()
{
    masterLvl = masterVolumeSlider.value;
    masterMixer.SetFloat("masterVol", masterLvl);
}

public void SetMusicVolume()
{
    musicLvl = musicVolumeSlider.value;
    masterMixer.SetFloat("musicVol", musicLvl);
}

public void SetSfxVolume()
{
    sfxLvl = sfxVolumeSlider.value;
    masterMixer.SetFloat("sfxVol", sfxLvl);
}
```

It has all the OnValueChanged(); things on the sliders. I just want to know why this doesn't work. Thanks.

EDIT: So the thing is that it changes the **dB**, not the volume. The new question is: How do I make it change the volume instead of dB?

EDIT 2: Screenshot.
[image: audiomixer screenshot]

Comment: I don't get any errors in console bye the way. Everything is assigned and working fine.

Comment: When you set break points and debugged this was the code in question getting hit?

Comment: Put `Debug.Log` in each function and see if they are being called....

Comment: I did put it. It works. Also, when I slide the musicVolumeSlider, it makes the volume more in an instance, but doesn't make it less again. It doesn't change at all. (background music volume)

Comment: Also, all my slider max values equal to 1 and my volume still goes up even though it's volume is 1 too.

Comment: Could it be that I don't change the volume, I change the dB? Edit: Yes, it is. Changed the question.

Comment: Can you post the screenshot of the AudioMixer in the Inspector tab?

Comment: Hi, just posted it. You can check it.

Comment: I mean, yes, it's the volume. But it's with dB's, not like a percentage or a 0-1 float.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think, your problem is that the mixer value (-80db - 20db) is a logarithmic scale and the slider value is linear. For example: half volume is actually about -10db, but if you connect it to a linear scale, like the slider, then half volume will end up being -40db! Which is why it sounds like it's basically silent at that point.

There's an easy way to fix it:

1. Instead of setting the slider min / max values to -80 and 20, set them to min 0.0001 and max 1.
2. In the script to set the value of the exposed parameter, use this to convert the linear value to an attenuation level:

   ```
    masterMixer.SetFloat("musicVol", Mathf.Log10(masterLevel) * 20);
   ```

It's important to set the min value to 0.0001, otherwise dropping it all the way to zero breaks the calculation and puts the volume up again.

Post:

https://forum.unity.com/threads/changing-audio-mixer-group-volume-with-ui-slider.297884/

Answer (score 2):

Here's a formula that sounds subjectively closer to how linear volume behaves usually:

```
    private float ValueToVolume(float value, float maxVolume)
    {
        return Mathf.Log10(Mathf.Clamp(value, 0.0001f, 1f)) * (maxVolume - zeroVolume) / 4f + maxVolume;
    }
```

- It looks [something like this](http://fooplot.com/#W3sidHlwZSI6MCwiZXEiOiJsb2coeCkqMjAiLCJjb2xvciI6IiMwMDAwMDAifSx7InR5cGUiOjEwMDAsIndpbmRvdyI6WyIwIiwiMSIsIi04MCIsIjAiXX1d).
- maxVolume can be used if your AudioMixerGroup "max" volume is not 0 but -20db for example.

Comment: zeroVolume? Do you mean 0f?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to deal with the dB to set the volume of a mixer. Set your slider's lower limit to -80 and upper limit to 20 and it will work fine with the mixer. If you do not want to deal with it You can either change the volume of the audio listener or the source.

Comment: Thanks. That's actually what I already did. I was just wondering if there was any way to do it. Seems like there aren't. Thanks again.