# How to set a slider's volume from the audio mixers's volume in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio, uislider, mixer

I have `audioMixerGroup.audioMixer.GetFloat("AllVolume", out tmp);`
tmp will have volume in db. I vant to convert db (-80, 0) to slider's value (0, 1).

in short, I need to do [How to set a Mixer's volume to a slider's volume in Unity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46529147/how-to-set-a-mixers-volume-to-a-sliders-volume-in-unity) **just the other way around**

Comment: The generic problem you are trying to solve is converting between a logarithmic (audio) scale and a percentage. As for Unity specific did you come across this? https://gamedevbeginner.com/the-right-way-to-make-a-volume-slider-in-unity-using-logarithmic-conversion/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a `Remap` function:

```
float Remap(float value, float min1, float max1, float min2, float max2) 
{
    return min2 + (value - min1) * (max2 - min2) / (max1 - min1);
}
```

Implementation:

```
audioMixerGroup.audioMixer.GetFloat("AllVolume", out tmp);
slider.value = Remap(tmp, -80f, 0f, 0f, 1f);
```

Answer (score 1):

When setting the volume you will utilize the following code:

```
Mathf.Log10(value) *20;
```

What you need is the inverse:

```
Mathf.Pow(10, (value/20);
```

Answer (score -1):

I would do the below when you need to use the tmp variable:

```
(tmp + 80f) * 0.01f
```